# « Pouvoir » ou « arriver à » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Pour exprimer que l'on ne comprend pas quelque chose, il me semble qu'il est très commun de dire:

> je n'arrive pas à comprendre

quand on veut dire

> je ne peux pas comprendre

Les mots veulent-ils dire la même chose ? Pourquoi préfère-t-on l'un ou l'autre ? Existe-il des contextes où on doit utiliser « pouvoir » et pas « arriver » ? (C'est clair qu'il faut utiliser « arriver » si c'est une histoire de venir à un endroit depuis un autre endroit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Je n'arrive pas à comprendre* : je ne trouve pas le chemin qui va conduire mon raisonnement à la solution :

> - Je n'arrive pas à comprendre comment ce magicien fait sont tour.

*Je ne peux pas comprendre* : je n'ai pas les moyens intellectuels, la formation, les connaissances pour comprendre ce problème :

> - Je ne peux pas comprendre les équations de mécanique quantique.

Bien sûr dans les échanges habituels on peut utiliser l'un pour l'autre pour manifester son désespoir.

Answer (score 5):

En français, on ne traduit pas *I can swim* par *je peux nager*, mais par *je sais nager*.

La même logique prévaut pour la négation : *je ne peux pas comprendre* ne peut avoir qu'un sens très spécifique, on s'attend à ce que vous donniez les raisons précises qui vous en empêchent, soit que vous soyez véritablement sot, pathologiquement inapte ou qu'on vous a caché certaines informations nécessaires à cette compréhension (ou défaut d'éducation).

Dans les autres cas, *je ne parviens pas à comprendre* (formule qui insiste sur l'effort de compréhension en train de se faire, et qui n'est pas terminé, donc la compréhension est toujours possible) ou plus simplement *je ne comprends pas* sont les seules traductions admissibles.

Answer (score 3):

Prenons l'exemple d'une scène de film ou un gangster sous la menace d'une arme ordonne à l'un de ses otages d'en abattre un second. Trois situations peuvent se produire

- premier cas: Il abat l'otage (cas inintéressant pour nous)
- second cas: il essaye de l'abattre mais est tellement paniqué qu'il se met à trembler comme une feuille et répond "Je n'y arrive pas, ... **je n'arrive pas à appuyer sur la gâchette, je n'arrive pas à l'abattre**..."
- Troisième cas: notre monsieur a déjà depuis longtemps résolu de ne jamais franchir certaines limites et préférerai plutôt mourir; il répond "je ne peux pas faire ça... **je ne peux pas l'abattre**..."